# Photos not going to iCloud from iPhone

Tags: icloud, photos

My photos stopped going to the iCloud in February.  When I logged into iCloud.com, there is nothing after 2-28-15.  I went to the Apple Store, and the genius guys said "fascinating."  They checked all kinds of things, and couldn't solve it.  My phone is 2+ years old, and I am due for a new one.  Will a new phone solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that adding another device to the mix will help.

Did the genius explain that AppleCare over the phone supports iCloud for issues like yours and [mine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177722/is-it-possible-to-wipe-an-entire-icloud-photo-library)?

If you have an iPad or can borrow one, you can test adding a new device to iCloud without needing to buy an iPhone.

Comment: The photos are all on my phone.  They have not gone to iCloud to show up on my iPad.  But, why are they not going to iCloud at all?  When I log into iCloud.com, they are not there.  I am due for a new phone, and wonder if there is a new operating system on it that will help.

Comment: @Carole Possibly. IF you want to edit your details into the question, it might make it easier to answer without 20 questions or guesswork. Basically - the requirements are at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201317 and you might consider adding a screen shot of your device to show the iCloud settings for photos.