# Delete photos from iCloud Photo Library faster

Tags: icloud

I've disabled the iCloud Photo Library on my iPhone and now have to wait 30 days to remove all photos from the iCloud (I don't need them on any of my Apple devices).

Is there a way to do it faster (without deleting every single photo manually)?

Comment: Dupe of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177722/is-it-possible-to-wipe-an-entire-icloud-photo-library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Login in iCloud.com (from a computer) with your Apple ID.
2. Click on Photos, then click on Albums at the top.
3. I'm not sure if disabling iCloud Photo Library on all devices causes your photos to be moved to Recently Deleted automatically or not, so if there are still items showing in All Photos, click on that. If not, skip to step 9.
4. Scroll to the top of the grid of photos.
5. Click Select Photos at the top toward the right side.
6. Click the first photo. Scroll to the bottom of the grid of photos. Press and hold the Shift key, and click the last photo.
7. Click the Delete button in the middle of the blue bar at the top.
8. Click "< Albums" at the top left.
9. Click on the Recently Deleted album.
10. Click Delete All at the top toward the right.

Comment: 3. No, it's not. 7. It's a bit strange, but the Delete button is deactivated if you disabled the iCloud Photo Library.

Comment: You would need to re-enable iCL and follow the steps above first, then disable it again. There is an option to pause downloading/uploading for a day within iCL settings; do that to avoid it trying to synchronize all photos in the meantime.