# Deleting all photos from iCloud immediately 2018

Tags: ios, icloud, photos

I would like to delete all of my photos from icloud immediately. The only way I have found to do this is select each individual picture and delete it. There does not seem to be a select all option anymore.

I already know about this. I just don't want to have to wait 30 days.

On your iDevice/s (iPhone, iPad, etc), go to Settings > Photos & Camera > and turn off the "iCloud Photo Library" option.

Comment: This is covered in several questions. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255646/delete-photos-from-icloud-photo-library-faster and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255646/delete-photos-from-icloud-photo-library-faster

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac you can open System Preferences -> iCloud
Click the "Manage..." button in the bottom right corner and then disable and delete the iCloud Photo Library.

[image]

Comment: You still have to wait 30 days for that. I don't want to have to wait 30 days. Thats why I was asking about a select all option.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I made a small script which do the job. It's simple as a pie, but "just works" ©. Script is implemented using [AHK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey), so you need to be a bit familiar with AHK concept and be able to properly set it up.

```
 #NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
 #Warn   ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
 #SingleInstance force
 SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
 SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
 ^!z::
 Loop, 30
 {
    Click
    Sleep 1000
     Send {Del}
     Send {Tab}
     Send {Enter}
    Sleep 1000
 }
```

`^!z::` here is the hotkey that starts the script (Ctrl-Alt-Z) and `30` is a number of loop iterations (number of photos to delete).

**Prior** to starting the script you should position mouse cursor on the upper left photo, for it to work.

I tested it just now and it deleted 1600 photos brilliantly.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Can't be done. Must delete one at a time. Thanks Apple