# Repost: Is it possible to wipe an entire iCloud Photo Library?

Tags: icloud, backup, photos

I was not happy with the answer to this question so I am posting it again with my own answer to [Is it possible to wipe an entire iCloud Photo Library?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177722/is-it-possible-to-wipe-an-entire-icloud-photo-library)