# How to delete all photos from iCloud library without having to manually delete every 1000 items?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

I have a friend which has 2 TB of media data. I backed it up to my PC and now I want to delete all files from iCloud so that she has free space again, but I am restricted to delete 1000 items at a time. She has more than 400.000 files so this is a time consuming task...

Is it really designed that stupid or is there an easy way to delete all media?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, Hi, I already deleted all media from the device.

Comment: Disabling and deleting in device's settings -> iCloud -> iCloud photo library.  Also, are you sure about recently deleted items album in photos-> albums, last option, Recently Deleted?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean with `Disabling and deleting in settings -> iCloud`. Yes I just deleted all media from the iPhone.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177722/is-it-possible-to-wipe-an-entire-icloud-photo-library?noredirect=1&lq=1 See my updated comment too/.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, I looked at the post which you have linked. But the accepted answer does not work, since you can only delete 1000 files at a time as I said.

Comment: That limitation is by design @Black - I’ll answer since there is a way to bulk delete in the photos app and a support alternative to bulk delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting photos is easy if you can borrow a Mac.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179483/5472

If not, you’ll want to pick away with it or open a support case with Apple. The engineers can blow away files if you give them a support PIN and they have a reasonable belief you can’t do it by plugging away with the tools Apple ships and you realize the limitations are there to prevent a moment where someone destroys another’s library when their phone is unlocked and not hassle someone that legitimately wants to remove thousands upon thousands of photos.

Comment: Another reason not to buy apple...

Comment: Thanks for helping a friend despite not agreeing with the decisions / implementation. 400k photos is amazing to get into the cloud assuming they’re all the 2 TB. I’ve not seen anyone max out yet, so quite the edge case you’re handling.

Comment: It is a family account so she is not the only person who makes photos.